# Disable spring health check for just 1 datasource without creating separate custom health indicator class?

Tags: java, spring, liquibase

I have multiple data sources in a single project but, would like to just disable health check for the below data source.

```
@Bean
@LiquibaseDataSource
public DataSource myliquibasedb() {
    ...
}
```

I would prefer to not have to manage health check for all of my datasources with a separate class just because I am trying to disable for one single instance. Is there by any chance an annotation or property that could achieve what I am looking for ?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?  If so, could you share it here?

Comment: @tabbyfoo No unfortunately I was only left with 2 options: Disable spring health checks all together or implementing a health check per data source. I tried going through liquibases files to see if there was a bean I could make it be conditional on but, I had no luck.